# Adding control to form from other class

Tags: c#, class, controls

I'm trying to create picturebox in class and add it to form with method, it doesn't have any errors but it doesn't display picturebox

Class:

```
class Igrac
{
        public int ID;
        public string Ime;
        public int Polje;
        public int Novac;
        public Igrac(int id, string ime, int polje, int novac)
        {
            ID = id;
            Ime = ime;
            Polje = polje;
            Novac = novac;
        }
        public void Pijun (int LocX,Image image, Form1 form)
        {
            PictureBox pijun = new PictureBox();
            pijun.Size = new Size(20, 40);
            pijun.Location = new Point(LocX,655);
            pijun.Image = image;
            form.Controls.Add(pijun);
        }
}
```

Main program:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Igrac igrac1 = new Igrac(1, ImeIgraca1, 0, 10000);
    igrac1.Pijun(643, Properties.Resources.Pijun1,this);
}
```

Comment: what is Igrica ???

Comment: Form's name, sorry i'll edit it now

Comment: Using the wrong form reference is the traditional mistake, but doesn't look like it when you pass `this`.  Add `form.Show();` so you can be 100% sure.  Getting the Location wrong and the control beyond the form bounds is easy to do, do note that the values you use a rather high.  So try low values.  And it is easy to get the control overlapped by another, add pijun.BringToFront().

Comment: @HansPassant It was overlapped by another control, thank you very much and sorry for taking your time! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was overlapped by another control...

Answer (score 0):

I have pasted your code and its works fine, but check parameters in `new Point(LocX, 655)` contructor. If it is larger than form size, control will be outer window, because (0,0) point is on left upper corner.